# Can't create Snowflake temporary stage with Apache Spark connector

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a scheduled script to fix/restore/update access privileges in Snowflake using `GRANT` and `REVOKE` SQL statements. We are using a *revoke all*, then *grant some* fashion.

Everything works fine when disconnecting/reconnecting to the Web UI, but some jobs using either ODBC or JDBC seem to be in a stale state.

Should we close all sessions or wait for them to finish? Or is there anything else we can do?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi @christophe can you elaborate a bit on "ODBC or JDBC seem to be in a stale state" what does that look like on your end, any error messages or issues you are seeing? It is possible to see all queries in the query history with the query id. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html ALSO - are you using a Materialized View for seeing the state of all access privileges with this method: https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/How-to-Capture-Snowflake-Users-Roles-and-Grants-Into-a-Table ?

Comment: Issue spotted! Spark connector creates internal stages, which are granted differently from external stages. We have to grant READ and WRITE access privileges for these internal stages. Thanks a lot for your answer Rachel.

Comment: Granting READ and WRITE access privileges on stages wasn't enough to work around the `SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'` error when Apache Spark connector is trying to execute `create  temporary stage if not exists identifier(spark_connector_unload_stage_oWjosa5asD)` SQL query, am I missing something?

Comment: I'll grant the `CREATE STAGE` access privilege on schema and give it a try.

Comment: Nope, error is still the same `SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'` when Apache Spark is executing `create  temporary stage if not exists identifier(spark_connector_unload_stage_ZRJnhFmC22)`.

Comment: Typo on my side, `CREATE STAGE` access privilege solved the issue with Apache Spark!

Comment: Glad to see that worked out, so the Spark connector needed different access privilege to create a stage (external). I know that is expected.

Comment: Yes, thanks Rachel for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE STAGE` access privilege on schema is required by the Apache Spark connector to create temporary stages.